# Add submenu on drawer react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using below code to show a menu on react native.  I need to show a submenu but I cannot figure out how.

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  drawerContentOptions={{
    activeTintColor: '#cee1f2',
    color: '#cee1f2',
    itemStyle: {marginVertical: 5, color: 'white'},
    labelStyle: {
      color: '#d8d8d8',
    },
  }}
  screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}
  drawerContent={CustomSidebarMenu}>
  <Drawer.Screen
    name="homeScreenStack"
    options={{drawerLabel: 'Home Screen'}}
    component={homeScreenStack}
  />
  <Drawer.Screen
    name="settingScreenStack"
    options={{drawerLabel: 'Setting Screen'}}
    component={settingScreenStack}
  />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

Here is Customesidebar code.

```
    // Import React and Component
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Alert, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

import {
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItemList,
  DrawerItem,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

const CustomSidebarMenu = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={stylesSidebar.sideMenuContainer}>
      <View style={stylesSidebar.profileHeader}>
        <View style={stylesSidebar.profileHeaderPicCircle}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 25, color: '#307ecc'}}>
            {'DishUp'.charAt(0)}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <Text style={stylesSidebar.profileHeaderText}>
          DishUp
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={stylesSidebar.profileHeaderLine} />

      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        <DrawerItemList {...props} />
        <DrawerItem
          label={({color}) => 
            <Text style={{color: '#d8d8d8'}}>
              Logout
            </Text>
          }
          onPress={() => {
            props.navigation.toggleDrawer();
            Alert.alert(
              'Logout',
              'Are you sure? You want to logout?',
              [
                {
                  text: 'Cancel',
                  onPress: () => {
                    return null;
                  },
                },
                {
                  text: 'Confirm',
                  onPress: () => {
                    AsyncStorage.clear();
                    props.navigation.replace('Auth');
                  },
                },
              ],
              {cancelable: false},
            );
          }}
        />
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
    </View>
    );
   };

      export default CustomSidebarMenu;

    const stylesSidebar = StyleSheet.create({
    sideMenuContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#307ecc',
    paddingTop: 40,
    color: 'white',
    },
    profileHeader: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#307ecc',
    padding: 15,
    textAlign: 'center',
     },
     profileHeaderPicCircle: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    borderRadius: 60 / 2,
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    textAlign: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
     },
     profileHeaderText: {
    color: 'white',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    profileHeaderLine: {
    height: 1,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#e2e2e2',
    marginTop: 15,
     },
    });
```

Here is what it looks like right now.  But I want to add a submenu inside Home and Screen. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47766564/need-to-show-expandable-list-view-inside-navigation-drawer

Comment: no, it will not work in my case

Comment: @AyushShukla add your `CustomSidebarMenu` code

Comment: Added @NooruddinLakhani

Comment: @AyushShukla I think you should go for the custom Drawer navigator

Comment: How i can achieve that

Comment: Can someone please help me on this issue.